# why different file sizes for laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

> Via Laravel Installer

```
laravel new blog
```

file size is 15.3 MB

> Via Composer Create-Project

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

file size is 17.1 MB

> also has different no of folders and files
> see this pic http://i62.tinypic.com/w8b47l.jpg
>
> which one should i use and whats the difference ?

Comment: when was the last time you updated the Laravel Installer?

Comment: @fadeys.work  yesterday !!! just started learning .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use either one, they should be the same.

Now, the differences that your seeing are subject to predefined dependancies on the Installer and how updated they are.

Using the composer create-project however, will ensure you to always have the latest version of the dependencies.

Having said that, the only difference should be the speed of the setup itself, so don't worry about any differences you see in the number of files, it should be okay.

good luck.